# Post 400 Error When Trying To Generate DepositAddress

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, axelar

I am trying to use the `getDepositAddress` from the AxelarJS Sdk. As referenced [here](https://docs.axelar.dev/dev/axelarjs-sdk/token-transfer-dep-addr)

```
const fromChain = CHAINS.TESTNET.POLYGON,
   toChain = CHAINS.TESTNET.AVALANCHE,
   destinationAddress = "0xF16DfB26e1FEc993E085092563ECFAEaDa7eD7fD",
   thisAsset = "wavax-wei";

 const depositAddress = await axelarAssetTransfer.getDepositAddress({
   fromChain,
   toChain,
   destinationAddress,
   thisAsset,
   options: {
     shouldUnwrapIntoNative: false,
   },
 });
 console.log(depositAddress);
```

This is the code I use on the frontend but the error in the picture is what pops up in the console browser.

[image]

Comment: provide the  definition for getDepositAddress function. Without this is not possible to privde you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for this. I got it working. I think the issue was that I was using a newer version of Nextjs and Rainbowkit/Wagmi and I do receive an error but finally receive the deposit address

Answer (score 1):

It seems you received an error because the expected field was not passed into the get deposit address function or was incorrect.

What you did was:

```
 const depositAddress = await axelarAssetTransfer.getDepositAddress({
      fromChain,
      toChain,
      destinationAddress,
      thisAsset,
      options: {
        shouldUnwrapIntoNative: false,
      },
    });
```

**Instead of**

```
const depositAddress = await axelarAssetTransfer.getDepositAddress({
    fromChain,
    toChain,
    destinationAddress,
    asset: thisAsset,
    options: {
      shouldUnwrapIntoNative: false,
    },
  });
```

The key you provided for the `asset` was incorrect. I hope this helps!